# How do I stop two elements from overlapping vertically?

Tags: html, css

Ok so first things first. I have a navigation bar at the top of my page, and I've set it's position property to fixed so that it stays on screen all the time.
The problem is that as soon as i did that the `div` below it shifted upwards going underneeth the `nav` element.

I have searched about this topic and found only solutions that involved setting the position property of the above `div` as relative. But doing so the navigation bar doesn't stay there, it moves with the rest of the page when scrolling down.

This is the code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  height: 30px;
  background: #006666;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="nav-bar">Navigation bar</nav>

  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
    nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
    officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</body>
```

I've tried different combinations of positions of both elements but none of them worked as i wanted.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e1nbxj8v/

Comment: add margin to the bottom element or use `position:sticky` instead of fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `padding-top:30px` of `.content`

```
.content {
  position: relative;
  background: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top:30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/yafeu1x7/

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. I didn't try it because I was looking for some sort of automatic positioning that wouldn't mess up with the responsiveness of the page. But I guess I'll just add the different paddings to my media queries.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you rather use a very simple CSS grid:

```
grid-template-rows: 30px calc(100vh - 30px);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-bar {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #006666;
  color: #fff;
}

.content {
  background: #aaa;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 30px calc(100vh - 30px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="nav-bar">Navigation bar</nav>

  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
    elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
    dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
    dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
    nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
    officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider adding `margin-top: 30px;` to content and nav making `top: 0;` ?

https://jsfiddle.net/dv7pyh92/1/